# Need help storing specific values from a 2 dimensional array

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, parsing

So I have a 2 dimensional array that looks like the following

```
    {1, 20}
    {1, 14}
    {2, 15}
    {2, 67}
    {3, 55}
    {3, 24} 
    {4, 95}
    {4, 23}
```

What I need to do is basically find the highest number in the 2nd column that corresponds to each number so for 1 the highest number is 20, for 2 the highest number is 67, etc... So I have tried to use a while loop that looks like this

```
int count = 0;
int count2 = 0;

int[][] array = {1, 20}
                {1, 14}
                {2, 15}
                {2, 67}
                {3, 55}
                {3, 24} 
                {4, 95}
                {4, 23}
int[] storeMax = new int[4]

while (array[0][count] < array[count].length)
            {
                if (array[count][1] > storeMax[count2])
                {
                    storeMax[count2] = degPerc[count][1];
                    count2++;
                }
                else
                {
                    count++;
                    count2++;
                }
            }
```

I have been at this for a while but can't seem to figure it out. If anyone can help me that would be awesome!

Comment: `array[0][count] < array[count].length` will fail in case `count` is 2 or more.

Comment: You also need commas after each array in the 2D array. Like: 

{ }, 
{ },
{ }

Comment: create Map<Integer, Integer> map . store key as first column and start putting value as second column (if key already exist check value and if value in map is less than current value replace with current value). atlast you will get your output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As i think one solution that is little bit different from your solution.

create `Map<Integer, Integer> map` . store key as first column and start putting value as second column (if key already exist check value and if value in map is less than current value replace with current value). atlast you will get your output

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[][] array = { { 1, 20 }, { 1, 14 }, { 2, 15 }, { 2, 67 },
            { 3, 55 }, { 3, 24 }, { 4, 95 }, { 4, 23 } };

    Map<Integer, Integer> map = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();
    System.out.println(array.length);
    for(int i=0;i<array.length; i++)
    {
        if(map.get(array[i][0]) == null)
                map.put(array[i][0], array[i][1]);
        else
            if(map.get(array[i][0]) < array[i][1])
            {
                map.put(array[i][0], array[i][1]);
            }
    }
    System.out.println(map);
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Just a quick question though. Is there a way to sort the order and format the print?

Comment: You can use a TreeMap instead of a HashMap to keep the items sorted (plus you can supply a comparator for custom sorting)

Comment: @dcbeast96  for sorting you can use  `Map<Integer, Integer> map = new TreeMap<Integer, Integer>();`

Answer (score 1):

If you use Java 8 you can use the new handy `Map.compute` method:

```
static int[][] array = { { 1, 20 }, { 1, 14 },
    { 2, 15 }, { 2, 67 }, { 3, 55 },
    { 3, 24 }, { 4, 95 }, { 4, 23 } };

public static void main(String args[]) {
    Map<Integer, Integer> m = new HashMap<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        int value = array[i][1];
        int key= array[i][0];
        m.compute(key, (k, v) -> v == null ? value : Math.max(v, value));
    }
}
```

Comment: I think it is far advanced for the OP who struggles at the basics of array

Comment: @Madhan that might be so, but answers on SO are not only to the benefit of the OP but for the community as a whole.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, the correct syntax for declaring a multi array like this would be

```
int[][] array = {{1, 20},
            {1, 14},
            {2, 15},
            {2, 67},
            {3, 55},
            {3, 24},
            {4, 95},
            {4, 23}};
```

So it seems that you are a bit unfamiliar with how multidimensional arrays work in java. It would probably be worth reading up on it. Just remember that a multidimensional array is just an array that is storing other arrays. The line

```
while (array[0][count] < array[count].length)
```

is probably not what you want. What you want to do is loop over the whole contents of the array, looking for the max value (2nd column) for each key (1st column). Try to loop like this.

```
int count = 0;
while(count < array.length){
  count++;
}
```

Now, you know that each entry in the array has a key at index 0 and a numeric value at index 1 so therefore you can check them like this

```
int count = 0;
while(count < array.length){
  int keyVal = array[count][0];
  int numVal = array[count][1];
  count++;
}
```

Lastly, your sample data only has the possible values for keys of 1-4. If all it will ever be is 1-4, then your storeMax variable will work to store the results. Otherwise, you will want to use a Map as Prashant says in the comments above.

So if the keys will always be between 1-4, then you can do a check in the loop and store them.

```
while(count < array.length){
    int keyVal = array[count][0];
    int numVal = array[count][1];

    if(storeMax[keyVal-1] < numVal){
        storeMax[keyVal-1] = numVal;
    }
    count++;
}
```

Remember that arrays are 0 based. That's why you have to use keyVal-1.